# Is there a way to specify a Class by having its Type?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

There is one problem. `OracleDataReader` can report the column `name`, `type`, and `value` by type.

```
int i = № of column 
string name = reader.GetName(i)
Type fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(i)
reader.GetFieldValue<T>(i)
```

The `GetFieldType` method returns a field `Type`.

For example:

```
Type fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(i)
fieldType.name = System.String
```

In the `GetFieldValue<T>` method instead of `T`, I specify the class `String` like...

```
string result = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(i);
```

Below is the code section where I iterate over `TypeCode`.

Is there a way to specify class by having its type?

```
var result = reader.GetFieldValue<fieldType.class>(i);

using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
        int count = reader.FieldCount;
        string[] rows = new string[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          rows[i] = String.Format(@"""{0}"":", reader.GetName(i));
          Type fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(i);

          if (reader.IsDBNull(i)) {
            DBNull nullValue = reader.GetFieldValue<DBNull>(i);
            rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(nullValue);
          } else {
            switch (Type.GetTypeCode(fieldType)) {
              case TypeCode.Boolean:
                bool boolValue = reader.GetFieldValue<bool>(i);
                rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(boolValue);
                break;
              case TypeCode.DBNull:
                DBNull nullValue = reader.GetFieldValue<DBNull>(i);
                rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(nullValue);
                break;
              case TypeCode.Int32:
                int intValue = reader.GetFieldValue<int>(i);
                rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(intValue);
                break;
              case TypeCode.Decimal:
                decimal decValue = reader.GetFieldValue<decimal>(i);
                rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(decValue);
                break;
              case TypeCode.DateTime:
                DateTime dateValue = reader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(i);
                rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(new DateTimeOffset(dateValue));
                break;
              case TypeCode.String:
                string stringValue = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(i);
                rows[i] += SerializeOracleValue(stringValue);
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"{{{String.Join(",", rows)}}}");
      }
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Empty");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to serialise all these values into an array of strings? That's probably why you're getting stuck in this type confusion.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing EntityFramework.  Why not just use that?  Or Dapper, if you want something a bit more lightweight.

Comment: @DavidG, I am serializing data from a database into a json string so as not to create a bunch of dbo structs. This feature is implemented by default in Oracle 12.1, but we have 12.0

Comment: If `SerializeOracleValue` is fine with taking an `object`, `reader.GetFieldValue<object>(i)` might suffice. Generics are a compile-time tool, so they won't be much help here.

Comment: @Heinzi, It will work. But I take the object first, then try to parse its string representation. Why all this, if I initially know its type and can pick it up in this form.

Comment: @AndrewDzhur: I don't see any string parsing in the code you posted.

Comment: (BTW: Your output format looks *a lot* like JSON. Have you considered using some existing library with built-in DataTable-to-JSON support, e.g. json.net?)

Comment: Heinzi, I solved this problem a long time ago, using the data in the object type))